# Communication between Windows-phone-7, MYSQL-database and PHP, using JSON-array?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, json, windows-phone-7

I'd like to have a simple connection between my MYSQL-database using PHP and JSON-arrays. I want to both send and receive data to database by using the Phone-7 app.

Anyone who has a good solution for using this type of communication for building a Phone7 application? I know how to do this in Android, but i don't know if it's possible to do the same using Phone7 developer SDK (Visual Studio, Express for Windows Phone).

I will program in Visual C#, Windows Phone Application.
If you have any solutions, please show me both Visual C#, PHP and JSON snippets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) for the communication. Should be easy enough for you to write a C# API for your service with this.

Your question is somewhat vague. I mean, Java and C# aren't that different when it comes to REST requestions, and parsing JSON. It's something you have libraries for in both languages, and besides that you just create the entities you wish to (de)serialize to.